# If believing that Jesus is God is that important, why doesn't Jesus say it more often?

Tags: life-of-jesus

Why did many of his disciples not even know it?

Jesus asked "Who am I?" to a bunch of his disciples. Out of so many, only Peter got it close. That he is the Messiah, son of the living God.

Even that is still vague. Cyrus is also a messiah. Judaism tends to think that God considers humans his children. http://www.cgg.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Library.sr/CT/PW/k/187/Cyrus-Gods-Anointed.htm

I mean if believing that Jesus is God is that important, wouldn't Jesus like say that a million time? Wouldn't that be the first thing his disciples know?

Update: I need to add that I wrote a million time figuratively. I mean if it's that important, he would have stressed that more so that his disciples would at least got it right when he ask, "Who am I?". In fact, even after his death and resurrection, his disciples are still divided. We have gnostic, judaizer, arians, and trinitarian. Yea I know that "the rest" are heretic. I also know that most christians think that the trinitarian are the "true" follower of Jesus. But put your self in historian shoes here. Early jesus followers differ from jews only in whether they believe Jesus is a messiah or not.

13 When Jesus came to the region of Caesarea Philippi, he asked his disciples, “Who do people say the Son of Man is?”

14 They replied, “Some say John the Baptist; others say Elijah; and still others, Jeremiah or one of the prophets.”

15 “But what about you?” he asked. “Who do you say I am?”

16 Simon Peter answered, “You are the Messiah, the Son of the living God.”

17 Jesus replied, “Blessed are you, Simon son of Jonah, for this was not revealed to you by flesh and blood, but by my Father in heaven. 18 And I tell you that you are Peter,[a] and on this rock I will build my church, and the gates of Hades[b] will not overcome it. 19 I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven; whatever you bind on earth will be[c] bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on earth will be[d] loosed in heaven.” 20 Then he ordered his disciples not to tell anyone that he was the Messiah.

He doesn't condemn those who think he's a prophet or Elia? He doesn't say, "Good job Peter. For the rest of you, you'd better answer that thing right because my dad would fry you in hell if you messed up." http://www.ancestralfindings.com/who/ . Even Peter doesn't say, "You're God, Homo Ousion, without the i". I mean if something is kind of important, shouldn't that be more explicit?

Comment: The vows I made to my wife when I married her are important; but I only had to say them once. Repeating something doesn't make it more important, and not repeating something doesn't make it less important.

Comment: Are you only seeking viewpoints that reflect beliefs of the Church of the Great God denomination?

Comment: I am looking at facts. Yes one way to know facts is to see what others actually believe and why. I noted that not all Jesus followers believe he is God. Atanasius is only one of many christian sects that happen to be the norm. The rest are slaughtered.

Comment: Jim you have the facts of the case wrong. I started to answer this by trying to set faacts straight, however quite honestly the tone of this question is sounding less and less like an honest attempt to learn about the facts and more like an agenda based rant. What do you want to do here? I'm willing to help organize this into a question the community isn't going to downvote into oblivion and maybe close, but you have to care and be willing to reconsider your preconceived ideas. Savvy?

Comment: I was the one that's wrong. Jesus ask what do people think I am. Not who do you think I am. So early answers are wrong. First answer is right by Peter. Why no body point that out?

Comment: Jim, **(A.)** "More Often" implies that he said it at least "once", if not "more"--and I don't believe you made this point.  **(B.)** Maybe reword this question: "Is Believing that Jesus is "The Most High, God", a Condition for Salvation?"  **(C.)** As Salvation is the primary/important issue at hand, that should get you all kinds of answers ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually he said it a lot. Enough to get himself killed for saying it. The Jews considered Jesus' statement that he was "the Christ, the Son of the living God" blasphemy, and Jesus' agreement with Peter's declaration is the reason they tried and executed him.

The disciples took a while to catch on, but not for lack of being told. Their dull, slow hearts took a lot of time to convince, and Jesus had a great deal to teach them before he stirred up the pot enough to end his ministry.

It is important to note, however, the disciples to a man eventually became so convinced their teacher Jesus was THE Christ that they devoted their lives to proclaiming that message. Most of them were also willing to die--and did--for the truth of it.

If anyone was in a position to know that Jesus was something less than what he claimed to be, his disciples would know, yet to a man (except for Judas) they went their separate ways proclaiming all over the world that Jesus was God and Lord.

Moreover, I suggest Jesus made his message so plain that after his resurrection the disciples were left with no doubts about who he was. Who dies for something they know is a lie?

Comment: can you give more quotation. As we know messiah doesn't mean God. Jesus did say something along, "I and the father" is one. Maybe He worked for his Dad? That is still open to interpretation. Arian christians are actually quite numerous. So is judaizers. Not all early jesus' followers think he is God. Konstantine, for example, is babtised by an Arian and his son is an Arian. And there is enough Arians to tople Rome. Early judaizers (which we consider heretics) are also followers of Jesus. Then we got this messianic jews or whatever.

Comment: Also saying that his disciples are dumb and stubborn will lead to another problem. All we know about Jesus are mainly from his disciples.

Comment: Dull slow heart != dumb. In fact it's quite different. And knowing that they were slow to believe actually strengthens the weight of their testimony since they were not gullible fall for anything types. It also gives me hope for some other folks that come to mind...

Comment: Yes. I read that in wikipedia. Still God in what sense? In avatar sense? So many "senses" are declared heretic by church.

Comment: Perhaps son of God doesn't mean God. Jews call many things sons of God.

Comment: @JimThio: There is certainly more than once sense in which Jews or anybody else could use the term, but Jesus very clearly pronounced himself to be God himself and when he used that term everybody knew what he meant by it.

Answer (score 9):

If Jesus had merely claimed to be God and done nothing else, people would protest His claim by asserting that He never did anything to prove His Deity.

What Jesus chose to do was to prove His Deity by what He did and said, and the result is that many people protest because He didn't specifically claim to be God often enough or clearly enough for them.

In reality, we really do not know how often Jesus claimed to be God, nor in how many ways.  The gospel accounts do not record every word that Jesus ever spoke.  Rather, the gospel writers chose to record certain things that were pertinent to the audience they targeted.  So, perhaps Jesus claimed to be God very clearly and very often, but that just wasn't recorded in the gospel accounts.  Again, we don't have an audio recording of everything Jesus ever said.

However, Jesus did certainly did demonstrate very clearly that He most certainly claimed to be the eternal Son of God.

He forgave sins, healed the sick, gave sight to the blind, walked on water, fed 5,000, raised the dead, demonstrated omniscience... the list goes on.

The gospel writers record that Peter was convinced that Jesus was the Son of God, and Jesus does not correct His conclusion.  On the contrary, Jesus affirms it:

> Simon Peter replied, "You are the Christ, the Son of the living God."
>   And Jesus answered him, "Blessed are you, Simon Bar-Jonah! For flesh
>   and blood has not revealed this to you, but my Father who is in
>   heaven.  Matthew 16:16-17 ESV

The disciples were convinced that He was the Christ, the Son of the living God.  In fact, John's whole point in writing his gospel was to convince others to believe that very thing.  The approach he chose to use in order to convince people was to show what Jesus did and let the strength of that evidence convince the reader.  In any court of law, a mere claim of something must be backed up by hard evidence.  A person's claim of innocence is irrelevant if all the evidence leads to the contrary.  Jesus' claim to Deity is attested to by a preponderance of evidence.  In fact, even if Jesus never took the stand an made the claim to His Deity, He could still be found "guilty as charged" based on the abundant evidence.

Answer (score 1):

Ego is a terrible thing and I am afraid that many who feel their beliefs are being offended will feel the need to defend them. Having stated that, Jesus didn't go around saying: "hey everyone, you must believe the bible is God's word" to be saved. Actually the bible we have wasn't created until many years after Jesus left the earth and the things written in it are not important to one's salvation.

Jesus stated: Joh 12:48  He that rejecteth me, and receiveth not my words, hath one that judgeth him: **the word that I have spoken, the same shall judge him in the last day.** 
Joh 12:49  For I have not spoken of myself; but the Father which sent me, he gave me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak. 
Joh 12:50  And I know that his commandment is life everlasting: whatsoever I speak therefore, even as the Father said unto me, so I speak.

So having stated the above, it is Jesus' teachings that teach us to walk in the light, not by mental acceptance of certain intellectual dogmas, but rather by how we live and thus Jesus stated, before the words written above, the following:

Joh 12:44  Jesus cried and said, He that believeth on me, believeth not on me, but on him that sent me. 
Joh 12:45  And he that seeth me seeth him that sent me. 
Joh 12:46  I am come a light into the world, that whosoever believeth on me should not **abide** in darkness. 
Joh 12:47  And if any man hear my words, and believe not, I judge him not: for I came not to judge the world, but to save the world.

Don't overlook that word "abide" as it is the whole point behind Jesus' speech here. It is how you live that matters.

I will suggest that what you mentally believe is totally irrelevant, it is how you live that matters.

Mat 7:13  Enter ye in at the strait gate: for wide is the gate, and broad is the way, that leadeth to destruction, and many there be which go in thereat: 
Mat 7:14  Because strait is the gate, and narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life, and few there be that find it. 
Mat 7:15  Beware of false prophets, which come to you in sheep's clothing, but inwardly they are ravening wolves. 
Mat 7:16  Ye shall know them by their fruits. Do men gather grapes of thorns, or figs of thistles? 
Mat 7:17  Even so every good tree bringeth forth good fruit; but a corrupt tree bringeth forth evil fruit. 
Mat 7:18  A good tree cannot bring forth evil fruit, neither can a corrupt tree bring forth good fruit. 
Mat 7:19  Every tree that bringeth not forth good fruit is hewn down, and cast into the fire. 
Mat 7:20  Wherefore by their fruits ye shall know them. 
Mat 7:21  Not every one that saith unto me, Lord, Lord, shall enter into the kingdom of heaven; but he that doeth the will of my Father which is in heaven. 
Mat 7:22  Many will say to me in that day, Lord, Lord, have we not prophesied in thy name? and in thy name have cast out devils? and in thy name done many wonderful works (Miracles)? 
Mat 7:23  And then will I profess unto them, I never knew you: depart from me, ye that work iniquity. 
Mat 7:24  Therefore whosoever heareth these sayings of mine, and doeth them, I will liken him unto a wise man, which built his house upon a rock: 
Mat 7:25  And the rain descended, and the floods came, and the winds blew, and beat upon that house; and it fell not: for it was founded upon a rock. 
Mat 7:26  And every one that heareth these sayings of mine, and doeth them not, shall be likened unto a foolish man, which built his house upon the sand: 
Mat 7:27  And the rain descended, and the floods came, and the winds blew, and beat upon that house; and it fell: and great was the fall of it.

Love your enemies is a nice philosophy, but if you are not committed to doing it: how are you a disciple (one disciplined in the teachings) of Christ? How are you a sheep if you don't follow the Sheppard?

Avoid intellectual dogmas and follow the practices of Christ.

A persons actions show you what they truly believe. God will judge all mankind according to his works and if men claim to believe in God and live like the devil they are deceived: if they think they will be okay on judgment day. But if one doesn't believe in God and turns his way to live like Jesus, in the practice of his teachings, they will be forgiven by God for their past transgressions.

Eze 18:20  The soul that sinneth, it shall die. The son shall not bear the iniquity of the father, neither shall the father bear the iniquity of the son: the righteousness of the righteous shall be upon him, and the wickedness of the wicked shall be upon him. 
Eze 18:21  But if the wicked will turn from all his sins that he hath committed, and keep all my statutes, and do that which is lawful and right, he shall surely live, he shall not die. 
Eze 18:22  All his transgressions that he hath committed, they shall not be mentioned unto him: in his righteousness that he hath done he shall live. 
Eze 18:23  Have I any pleasure at all that the wicked should die? saith the Lord GOD: and not that he should return from his ways, and live? 
Eze 18:24  But when the righteous turneth away from his righteousness, and committeth iniquity, and doeth according to all the abominations that the wicked man doeth, shall he live? All his righteousness that he hath done shall not be mentioned: in his trespass that he hath trespassed, and in his sin that he hath sinned, in them shall he die. 
Eze 18:25  Yet ye say, The way of the Lord is not equal. Hear now, O house of Israel; Is not my way equal? are not your ways unequal? 
Eze 18:26  When a righteous man turneth away from his righteousness, and committeth iniquity, and dieth in them; for his iniquity that he hath done shall he die. 
Eze 18:27  Again, when the wicked man turneth away from his wickedness that he hath committed, and doeth that which is lawful and right, he shall save his soul alive. 
Eze 18:28  Because he considereth, and turneth away from all his transgressions that he hath committed, he shall surely live, he shall not die. 
Eze 18:29  Yet saith the house of Israel, The way of the Lord is not equal. O house of Israel, are not my ways equal? are not your ways unequal? 
Eze 18:30  Therefore I will judge you, O house of Israel, every one according to his ways, saith the Lord GOD. Repent, and turn yourselves from all your transgressions; so iniquity shall not be your ruin. 
Eze 18:31  Cast away from you all your transgressions, whereby ye have transgressed; and make you a new heart and a new spirit: for why will ye die, O house of Israel? 
Eze 18:32  For I have no pleasure in the death of him that dieth, saith the Lord GOD: wherefore turn yourselves, and live ye.

You may think I didn't answer you question, but I did. Believing in Jesus as God, or whatever, is totally irrelevant: it is how you live that matters.

Comment: "Believing in Jesus as God, or whatever, is totally irrelevant: it is how you live that matters." This is far from a common Christian understanding. Further, the question implies the frame that belief that Jesus is God *is* necessary, and since many Christians believe that, answers should be from that frame.

Answer (score 0):

In my view Jesus was highly literate in Tanakh, (he quotes at least four prophets and the psalms), and convinced that he was the Messiah.  But, he preached, as did John, that God's Kingdom was 'at hand', and believed that when it arrived his status would be revealed unambiguously to all.  So there was no point in trying to convince audiences from the literary evidence that he was Messiah.  They may never even have heard of the notion, or read any of the prophets.  His job was to get on and lead them to think and live as intending members of the kingdom.  There is a parallel in the life of Albert Schweitzer.  He went to Africa as a qualified doctor.  But he didn't convince the Natives that he was a doctor by showing them his certificates.  He healed lethal diseases, as did Jesus.  Once he had healed a couple of cases of sleeping sickness people came from everywhere.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score -3):

jesus never claimed to be god and neither did his disciples believe he was god. on the contrary, they believed he was the messiah the son of the god of their fathers.This was clearly illustrated in acts 5:30 where peter says that the god of their fathers, (ie the beign who spoke to abraham,isaac,jacob and moses through angels) raised jesus from the dead. This clearly shows that they knew that jesus was not the god of their fathers and that it was the god of their fathers who raised and glorified his servant jesus.

Comment: Sorry.  Jesus *did* claim to be God.  Check out John.  And the same Peter you quote in Acts 5 directly said, "You are the Christ, the son of the Living God."

Comment: When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent).

Comment: +1 . You are he christ, the son of the Living God does not equal You are God. Even claiming that one is one with God doesn't mean claiming that one is God. Kabalists also claim that Torah, Israel, and God are one.

Comment: @Jim Thio: -1. There may be some truth in what you say about the title "Messiah" not necessarily being equal to "God." When Jesus equated himself to the great I AM of Exodus 3:14 in John 8:59, however, the Jews "picked up stones to throw at Him." Why? Because they believed Jesus was guilty of blasphemy, a sin punishable by death (see Leviticus 24:16). By the way, at least 11 popular English versions of the Bible have Jesus saying "I AM," and not "I have been" (New World Translation) or "I existed" (New Living Translation).

Comment: @omniscient: I don't believe in down-voting without justification, so I will at least reveal myself as having done so. Please, either change your username or, at least, attempt to live up to it.There are so many errors of interpretation in the scant scripture you make reference to, not to mention your understanding of Jewish thought, that a down-vote here requires no justification, at all. Please read the Bible along with a widely accredited commentary, and find some spiritual guidance. John 1:1 the Word was God and persists in context here; John 1:14, the Word became flesh. John's intent here

Comment: @Abstraction it's ironic that you claim to 'know' scripture - advising someone else yet you've misread it completely. John 1:1-3 speaks of the word - not Jesus. The word was *with* God, making it not God as God is God. Yes, 1John 1 describes the logos as a 'what, a 'which' not a living entity. When did the logos become flesh? When Jesus was conceived. So the John 1:1-3 cannot speak of Jesus because the logos was not yet flesh. These are the simple facts requiring no interpretation. Jesus is only God when people read it in.